# How can I load posts starting from, and including, the current post?

Tags: loop

I'm loading some posts using this argument:

```
$args = array(
 'category__in' => $catID,
 'category__not_in' => 1,
 'posts_per_page'=>10,
 'date_query' => array( array( 'before' => get_the_date() ) )
);
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to include the actual post I'm on, this carries on after the current post.

I've tried adding `'offset'=>-1` but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I load posts starting from, and including, the current post?

**Edit: I've tried using `inclusive` but it didn't seem to work.**

```
<? php
$args = array(
    'category__in' = > $catID,
    'category__not_in' = > 1,
    'posts_per_page' = > 10,
    'date_query' = > array('before' = > get_the_date(), 'inclusive' = > true));
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop - > have_posts()) {
    $loop - > the_post();
    get_template_part('sidebar-posts-template');
}
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: `'date_query'` has an argument `'inclusive'` that you can set to `true`, in this way you will return also the posts published in the date the current post was posted. See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

Comment: How about storing the ID of your current post and add it into search result, eg LI if you print in front.. ?

Comment: @G.M. Yea sorry I fell asleep. I came across that and it didn't seem to work. I'll update my question to show `inclusive`.

Comment: @user4517 I'm not sure what you mean, could you expand a little? I gather that I can find out my post ID but would I feed a specific post as an argument in a custom loop?